# Eclipse Mylyn to GitHub connector on Eclipse Luna

Tags: eclipse, github, egit, mylyn

I am trying to install the Eclipse Mylyn to GitHub connector for Mylyn on Eclipse Luna.  Not having much success yet.  From other posts I found the update site URL for the connector should be http://download.eclipse.org/egit/github/updates/.  This seems to work.  I get "Collaboration" and the "Eclipse GitHub integration with task focused interface" option. When I try to install I get the following error:

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.egit,3.5.1.201410131835-r
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.egit.core,3.5.1.201410131835-r
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.egit.doc,3.5.1.201410131835-r
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.egit.mylyn.ui,3.5.1.201410131835-r
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.egit.ui,3.5.1.201410131835-r
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jgit,3.5.1.201410131835-r
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jgit.archive,3.5.1.201410131835-r
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.egit,3.5.1.201410131835-r
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.egit.mylyn,3.5.1.201410131835-r
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.jgit,3.5.1.201410131835-r
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: I created a bug for this issue here: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=450485

Answer (score 1):

I've been able to get this working with Luna.  Go to install new software and use "http://download.eclipse.org/releases/luna" as the URL.  This gets a lot of Luna packages.  Type "git" in the filter field to find only git related software. I selected and installed all the git related softaware and this was able to complete successfully

[image]

Comment: This only increased the number of plugins that could not be installed.